# scikit support to scale features between [0,1] or [-1,1]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

scikit-learn's SVM is based on LIBSVM. LIBSVM/SVM requires that the data should be scaled and the recommendation is that a feature value should be in one of the two ranges [0, 1] or [-1, 1]. That is, in the typical matrix, each column is a feature and the scaling is done per column.

LIBSVM FAQ suggests a simple scaling to get the features between [0, 1]:

```
x'=(x-min)/(Max-min)
```

Does scikit-learn support this "simple scaling"? Are there other recommendations for scaling the features to use with SVM and RBF kernel. Any references? I found a reference article called "A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification" that is based on LIBSVM and they recommend scaling to [0, 1] or [-1, 1].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is included. The exact formula you describe will be in the next release as `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`. For now, [`sklearn.preprocessing.Scaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Scaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Scaler) (to be renamed `StandardScaler` in the next release, but the old name will stay around for backward compat) centers and scales features to have mean 0 and variance 1, which should be good enough for passing data to an SVM learner.

Also, [`sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer) (and the `TfidfVectorizer` that is used for text classification) normalizes values *per sample* into the range [0, 1]. This amounts to the length normalization that is common in text classification and information retrieval.

You can use a `Pipeline` object to construct a centering, scaling SVM classifier:

```
clf = Pipeline([('scale', Scaler()),
                ('svm', SVC())])
```

Comment: Thanks Larsmans! It is clear that the preprocessing.Scaler() is standardizing the columns (mean zero, var=1). However, I am not getting my values in range [-1,+1]. I have a matrix a. I am using the following code: scal = preprocessing.Scaler(), scal.fit(a), scal.transform(a). The results are not in the range [-1,+1].

Comment: @user963386 make sure that your matrix contains floating point values.  Scalers won't work properly otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler), at least for the [-1,1] case.

Comment: Only in the bleeding-edge version; this class was still called `Scaler` in the latest release. See my answer for details.